# Imacro EVAL to replace only Last Extract

Tags: imacros

Imacro Eval command only with Last extract(1), as it's available on javascript.

```
VERSION BUILD=7400919 RECORDER=FX
TAB T=1
URL GOTO=http://android-developers.blogspot.com/2011/09/preparing-for-handsets.html
SET !EXTRACT_TEST_POPUP NO
EXTRACT SOME TAG
EXTRACT SOME TAG
EXTRACT SOME TAG
EXTRACT SOME TAG
TAG POS=1 TYPE=P ATTR=TXT:Early<SP>this<SP>year,* EXTRACT=TXT
SET !VAR1 EVAL("var s=\"{{!EXTRACT}}\"; s.toUpperCase()")
PROMPT {{!VAR1}}
```

So if i use the {{!EXTRACT}} in eval, it will replace from complete extraction of last 5 extract. However i want to uppercase only my last EXTRACT.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

you can't do it directly but you can use simple workaround:

```
URL GOTO=http://android-developers.blogspot.com/2011/09/preparing-for-handsets.html
SET !EXTRACT_TEST_POPUP NO
EXTRACT SOME TAG
EXTRACT SOME TAG
EXTRACT SOME TAG
EXTRACT SOME TAG
set !var2 {{!extract}}
set !extract null
TAG POS=1 TYPE=P ATTR=TXT:Early<SP>this<SP>year,* EXTRACT=TXT
SET !VAR1 EVAL("var s=\"{{!EXTRACT}}\"; s.toUpperCase()")
add !var2 {{!var1}}
PROMPT {{!VAR2}}
```